# aws billing for RI instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-billing

I was looking at my client's aws invoice and found out the EC2 instances were grouped based on ec2 family. For ex:

- m4.large
- m4.xlarge
- m4.2xlarge
- m4.4xlarge

I saw an entry of a EC2 machine of type m4.4xlarge under each group. Strangely, a different cost was applied on this same machine type (m4.4xlarge).

Under m4.large group, m4.large machine price was applied, under m4.xlarge group, m4.xlarge machine price was applied and so on.

Why is that? I understand that my client must have reserved instances of different machine type? But shouldn't be price based on normalisation factor?

Or does aws adjust the number of hours? For ex. under m4.large group, it multiply the m4.4xlarge machine type usage hours to 16. And under m4.xlarge group, it mutliply m4.4xlarge machjine usage hour to 8 and so on?

Answer (score 0):

Reserved instances are billed at the day of the purchase (except for the related tax charges, which might be charged at a later date)

So if someone has access to the Cost Management Console, can filter "Purchase Option: Reserved" and see whether any RI purchase was performed in the specified time range.

This should clear out any doubt on whether such purchase took place.

Then one can correlate this charge in the EC2 console under "Reserved Instances" tab in the equivalent region.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: That's mostly not true, First of all your can purchase "partial upfront" and "no upfront" which causes different types of billing. other things are not accurate as well.

Answer (score 0):

Reserved instances are applied in a very straightforward way. Note that RIs can apply to different **sizes** but it has to be the same family. In "Compute saving plans" you can use it for different families as well.

about your question on normalization:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/apply_ri.html

Instance size flexibility is determined by the normalization factor of the instance size. The discount applies either fully or partially to running instances of the same instance family, depending on the instance size of the reservation, in any Availability Zone in the Region. The only attributes that must be matched are the instance family, tenancy, and platform.

Instance size flexibility is applied from the smallest to the largest instance size within the instance family based on the normalization factor.